# PHP strcmp("", "") return 1

Tags: php, string, comparison, strcmp

i have a code like this:

a certain point:

```
$buffer="";
```

and after some other line of code

`strcmp($buffer, "")` it returns 1

- I check that any code modify $buffer;
- `echo " '".$buffer."' ";`  prints ''
- I check the ascii value of $buffer with echo ord($buffer) and it prints 0
- Finally I check like `strcmp($buffer, NULL)` and `strcmp($buffer, '')` and it's always the same things...in the php function `strcmp` returns 1 but if i try `strcmp("", "")` in  another page returns 0

Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: https://3v4l.org/Z5MtP Check for error somewhere else.

Comment: It would help I could see your whole code from the variable declaration until the `strcmp` call. However, if you want to check whether `$buffer` is an empty string, why not just use `empty($buffer)` ?

Comment: Thank you, in fact the use of empty() is the better choice because i found my problem and it's that strcmp( chr(0), "") it returns 1 instead empty() returns true for all the case chr(0), "", null .                                                                $buffer=chr(0);
 echo strcmp($buffer, ''); 
 if(empty($buffer))
  echo "<br>true";
 else
  echo "<br>true";
 $buffer="";
 if(empty($buffer))
  echo "<br>true";
 else
  echo "<br>true";
 $buffer=null;
 if(empty($buffer))
  echo "<br>true";
 else
  echo "<br>true";